# Querying sys.dm_exec_sessions and sys.dm_exec_connections without granting the VIEW SERVER STATE permission

Tags: sql-server

Normally I have ordinary users that connect to my SQL Server database and execute stored procedures in the schema named `myschema`.

If these users try to get data from tables of the database, they do not see any tables, but they can access the tables through a stored procedure in `myschema`.

Now I am querying `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections` and would like to have the same approach, but no, I have to grant the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to an user that is calling the `myschema.GetUserSessions` procedure!

After all I want that users only have access to some fileds of `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections`, not to the whole views, and only through this very stored procedure, but not directly.

Currently I am using a workaround that is checking the permission and returning an empty result set with the right data types:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myschema.GetUserSessions
AS
    /* To be able to run this procedure an user should have VIEW SERVER STATE permission:
    USE master;
    GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [HOST\Username];
    */

    IF EXISTS(SELECT permission_name FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') WHERE permission_name = 'VIEW SERVER STATE') BEGIN
        SELECT
            ses.login_name,
            ses.[host_name],
            con.client_net_address,
            ses.[program_name],
            ses.login_time,
            ses.last_request_start_time,
            ses.last_request_end_time,
            con.net_transport,
            con.encrypt_option
        FROM
            sys.dm_exec_sessions ses
            inner join sys.dm_exec_connections con on con.session_id = ses.session_id
        WHERE
            is_user_process = 1
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT
            login_name = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR),
            [host_name] = CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR),
            client_net_address = CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR),
            [program_name] = CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR),
            login_time = CAST(0 AS DATETIME),
            last_request_start_time = CAST(0 AS DATETIME),
            last_request_end_time = CAST(NULL AS DATETIME),
            net_transport = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR),
            encrypt_option = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR)
        WHERE
            1 = 0
    END
```

Honestly to say I do not like an idea of neither granting the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to users nor saving the data from time to time to some intermediate table.

Comment: "*I do not like an idea of neither granting the VIEW SERVER STATE permission to users*" - Why?

Comment: @J.D.: Because the permission is granted for the whole, and I need only for a part.

Comment: Sure, but do you know what that permission actually does to be afraid to grant it? Also the use case is a little confusing. Why do end users who don't have view server state access need the ability to see certain columns about all user sessions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [module signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to accomplish this since you're already creating stored procedures for this end result. Depending on your use cases, this might be many modules.

If you're going to show everyone all of the results anyway, I'm not sure the need to do module signing and the aversion to view server state, but it's not my environment, either. You have various choices, choose one or multiple, but it's going to be constrained by the product "limitations". If none of those work for you, then either don't let people see it or make a concession.